# Issue with social sharing plugin in Android 6.0

Tags: ionic-framework, android-6.0-marshmallow

In ionic,
I am using  eddy social share plugin:
https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin
It worked fine with below versions of Android 6.0.
In Android 6.0, it is not sharing to facebook.
By setting facebook permissions manually then social share with fb working fine.
Please suggest a solution to dynamically set permissions for social share apps in Android 6.0 through my ionic app.

Comment: Share your code, so that people can figure out the problem.